# Redemption library supports MS Outlook 365?

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-redemption

Would like to confirm if the Redemption library supports Microsoft Outlook 365, can someone plz confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, M365 is fully supported. Keep in mind however, that `RDOSession.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox` assumes Basic authentication is enabled. It can take OAuth toke as well (leave the user name empty and pass the OAuth token in place of the Password parameter), but how you get that token is a different matter - you cannot directly get the token from Office 365: the scopes required by the MSEMS MAPI provider cannot be requested from a regular app registered in your tenant. They are specific to Outlook.

If your code is running inside Outlook (COM addin or VBA), just set the `RDOSession.MAPIOBJECT` parameter to `Namespace.MAPIOBJEC`T from OOM - that will force Redemption to use the same session used by Outlook, no matter what kind of mailbox the profile is working with.